# Mostly no difference between before and after editing

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

After I upload a question, then some user (mostly high-level user) edit my question.

But many times I don't see any difference.

I wonder what they edited and why they edit it.

I don't have the slightest hostility in my question, I'm just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: You can click on the red link [**edited XX mins ago**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV7Vr.png) that appears under your question, and you will see the differences. For example, in your latest two questions ([Q1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/282972/revisions), [Q2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/282313/revisions)), the user capitalized the title of your questions.

Comment: Wow, thank you again!

Comment: Ref: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/editing -- The guidelines do state "**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged**." I suppose what is considered trivial varies. Fixing spelling esp. of keywords, fixing grammar esp. when the original is unclear,...these might be considered tiny nontrivial edits. These are listed as valid edit reasons in the reference. The "esp." conditions are my own additions and not required by the reference.